# ssas mdx: query gone wrong

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm getting the error: Query (9, 7) The '[Total Earnings]' member was not found in the cube when the string, [Measures].[Total Earnings], was parsed.

-- common enough, but I just don't see where in the query. Hopefully one of you will spot it, or have a better approach Here's what I have:

```
  with
     member measures.[Total all Earnings] as [Total Earnings]
      (measures.[Total GS Earned]) + (measures.[Total DSE Earned]) + (measures. [Total Shares Earned])
   set [Top 10 Interstate Earnings] as
    topcount 
    (
      {Stores.[Interstate]. [Interstate].members},
       10,
       (Measures.[Total Earnings], [Time].[C Year].[2011])
     )
    select
    {([Measures].[Total Earnings])} on columns,
      {[Top 10 Interstate Earnings]} on rows
       from LoyaltyMeasurements
       Where (Time.[C Year].[2012]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a dufus... never mind. I didn't see until I pasted it!

the first line should be as follows for the calculated member:

```
  with
     member measures.[Total Earnings] as
```